# Object to CSV format and Export in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, csv

After exporting to CSV large strings are taking and rewriting other cells screenshot
[Result of export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqDSQ.png)

Link to jsfiddle Code
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/0khxo91u/2/)
Question is how to keep lar string in the cell that it does not affect other cell data

```js
var newS = {
        Name: "https://www.someweb.com/product/2019-new-shoulder-bags-leather-bucket-bag/452346283.html?d1_posid=6c776030d97bebe241c60070a53e7683&dspm=pcen.hp.relatedviewed.3.qJcEmZmc4A8ZV2ksdlct&resource_id=452346283#hp1507_reit-3-5|null:2001:r1045009996.json",
        rating: "Google Inc",
        rating: "Google Inc",
        Price: "554.52"
    }
stockData.push(newS);
}
```

```js
function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
    var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

    data = args.data || null;
    if (data == null || !data.length) {
        return null;
    }

    columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
    lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    result = '';
    result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
    result += lineDelimiter;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
        ctr = 0;
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

            result += item[key];
            ctr++;
        });
        result += lineDelimiter;
    });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the part you have shown us, but in the actual `downloadCSV` function that is only contained in your fiddle.

```
if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
}
data = encodeURI(csv);
```

`encodeURI` is almost never the right choice, when it comes to properly encoding data for an URL context.

This needs to use `encodeURIComponent` instead - but because that would encode characters inside `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,` as well, these two steps also need to happen in the opposite order:

```
csv = encodeURIComponent(csv)
csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
data = csv; // keept this, so the rest of your code can still work with the data variable
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vky7b5dg/

I removed the if condition here - if the data already contained `data:text/csv` at the start, it would not work anyway. Then that would need to be removed *before* the URL encoding happens, and added again afterwards. This function appears to try and be very generic, but it doesn’t look like you need that part for your particular use case here.

---

(This still completely lacks any proper escaping of the data for the CSV context, of course. Should any of your data fields ever contain a `,`, this will still mess up. That, however, is an issue of the `convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV` function, and not this one that handles the download part.)

Comment: I just was trying to add a larger string and once again I broke the code https://jsfiddle.net/6Lntvh0u/1/ i little bit don't understand about that CSV exporting there are some kind limits

Comment: This is not because the strings are “longer”, but exactly because of what I said at the end - your function `convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV` does not handle escaping of the delimiter character, when it occurs inside the _data_, correctly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules

Comment: Yes I read your reply twice ) but how can I fix it I'm stuck..?

Comment: Still Stuck I don't get the point how to upgrade existing code to make it work as planed

Comment: Basically, replacing this one line `result += item[key];` inside the loop with `result += ('"' + String(item[key]).replace(/"/g, '""') + '"');` should do the trick. That adds `"` as delimiter around all the field values (takes care of the situation where that value might contain a `,`), and replaces any `"` that might be inside, with `""`.

Comment: Thank you i modified the script now it works as I need (was stuck for 24h)